# Unable to register dll gac using powershell or without gacutil in windows server 2012

Tags: c#, powershell, batch-file, dll, windows-server-2012

Please can you any help me ,why powershell keeps throwing below error message

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> .\Register_dll.cmd

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.EnterpriseServices, Version=1.0.0.0,
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7f48c3199e5dff41")
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>$publish = New-Object System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish
'$publish' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>$publish.GacInstall("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Mydll.dll")
'$publish.GacInstall' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Below is the batch file i have ran in Powershell as Administrator and i have verified the version and publictoken .I guess that is not the issue here.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.EnterpriseServices, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7f48c3199e5dff41")            
$publish = New-Object System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish 
$publish.GacInstall("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyDll.dll")
```

Comment: You're trying to use powershell syntax in a command batch script. Powershell scripts use the `.ps1` extension.

Comment: Thanks that helped .Sorry i am new to Powershell

Answer (score 1):

Your script needs to be saved as .ps1. It currently has the extention of .cmd which is making the PowerShell call the old Command shell to execute it which then doesn't recognise the PowerShell commands.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this a while ago to allow me to remote install GAC assemblies. Save this script as a module (.psm1) or a script (.ps1), import it, and run Install-GACAssembly:

```
Set-Variable GAC_VS2015_ASSEMBLY_REGKEY -option ReadOnly -value "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx"

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a") | Out-Null

function Install-GACAssembly {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [ValidateScript({ Test-Path $_ -PathType Container })]
        [string] $AssemblyDir,

        [Parameter()]
        [switch] $DevMode,

        [Parameter()]
        [string] $DevRegKeyName,

        [Parameter()]
        [switch] $uninstall
    )
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

    if($DevMode -and [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($DevRegKeyName)) {
        throw "If `$DevMode is true, a unique folder name must be specified in `$DevRegKeyName i.e. 'MyClient'"
    }
    if($DevMode) {
        New-Item -Path $GAC_VS2015_ASSEMBLY_REGKEY -Name $DevRegKeyName -Value $AssemblyDir -Force | Out-Null
    }

    $installText = "$(if ($uninstall) { "un" })install"
    Write-Verbose "Searching '$AssemblyDir' for GAC .dll files to $installText"

    $publisher = New-Object System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish            

    $assemblies = Get-ChildItem $AssemblyDir -Filter "*.dll"
    Write-Verbose @"
Found $($assemblies.Count) .dll files:
$($assemblies.FullName)
"@

    $assemblies | % {
        if(!$uninstall) {
            Write-Verbose "    Installing $($_.FullName) into the GAC"
            $output = $publisher.GacInstall($_.FullName)
        } else {
            Write-Verbose "    Removing $($_.FullName) from the GAC"
            $output = $publisher.GacRemove($_.FullName)
        }
    }

    Write-Verbose "GAC $installText finished"
    Write-Verbose "===================================="
}
```

If you create a module (.psm1) you have to import it into your powershell script / session using `Import-Module`:

```
PS D:\> Import-Module -Name "D:\Path-to-module\ModuleFileName.psm1" -Force
Install-GACAssembly -AssemblyDir "D:\Path-to-your-assembly\assembly-name.dll"
```

You can also use it to uninstall:

```
PS D:\> Import-Module -Name "D:\Path-to-module\ModuleFileName.psm1" -Force
Install-GACAssembly -AssemblyDir "D:\Path-to-your-assembly\assembly-name.dll" -uninstall
```

You can see verbose output by using the -Verbose flag on either command.

Comment: Can i know how do i run above script powershell by providing dll file path ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself for the question.

Firstly as Mark stated we need to run have file extension as .PS1 because it is a PowerShell script.

And then run below command to to successfully register the DLL.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.EnterpriseServices") | Out-Null 
[System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish] $publish = new-object System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish
$publish.GacInstall("MYdllFile.dll")
```